# инпуты типа текст меняют состояние по событию

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Имеется вот такое окно.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" 
 role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria- 
hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New 
 message</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-l 
 abel="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
   </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:. 
 </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:. 
 </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
   dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send 
   message</button>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Сделать инпуты видимыми с границей, курсором только после нажатия, а так просто тексты в виде label.

Реализовать через ботстрап или css файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #00000000;
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text 1" />
<input type="text" placeholder="text 2" />
```

Comment: Проверил, у меня работает только так:
`input {border: none;}

input:focus {border: 1px solid blue;}`

Comment: @Alexan-Dwer, нет, в твоём варианте будет прыгать при клике. Просто замени `#00000000` на `transparent` или `rgba(0,0,0,0)`.

Comment: @Qwertiy в моем варианте?

Comment: @Alexan-Dwer, прыгать - в твоём, а заменить цвет - в варианте из ответа.

Comment: @Qwertiy в какой момент что-то "будет прыгать"? Я не совсем понял, о чем Вы.

Comment: @Alexan-Dwer  Qwertiy имеет в виду, что второй инпут будет сдвигаться на 2 пикселя по появлении рамки вокруг первого

Comment: @Igor, да. И ещё высота строки будет меняться, соответственно последующий контент подвинется по вертикали.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, конечно, пардон. Тот же эффект - по вертикали.

Comment: Igor спасибо за разъяснение.
@Qwertiy для меня это не было важным, я просто внес примечание о синтаксисе. Как там автору вопроса будет нужно выполнить визуализацию, это уже другое дело...

Comment: @Alexan-Dwer, ну это плохо, что неважно...